# Volusion Image Size

Tags: volusion

Does someone know where I can go in my Volusion template to set an exact size for products to be displayed on the category pages? I have some images that have a width of 300px and some with a width of 280px so I would like to have the parameter set to 280px by 260px for all pictures.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it, you can set the product image size for homepage, product page, and big image once you upload it, and you can save that option to reflect on future items. On past items there is no other way but to manually reupload their respective images and make their size designated to your preferences

Answer (score 0):

Since we have thousands of legacy product photos of varying sizes, I wrap the photo with a div so I can have the same height and width (padded) across all photos.

For the product detail page (similar on category page):

JS:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery('#product_photo').wrap('<div class="product_photo_container"></div>');
});
```

CSS:

```
.product_photo_container {
    border: 1px dotted #999;
    height: 250px;
    line-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}
```